# IE9 firing onbeforeunload event when the window opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, onbeforeunload

I'm building a site using the [JFileUpload](http://www.jfileupload.com) applet and want to handle the closing of a page in a certain way. JSTransferCancelled is called when the applet is cancelled. The following code is what I'm using to handle these events and it works in all browsers except IE.

```
        function JSTransferCancelled(){
            bCancel=false;
            $.post("cancel.php");
            self.close();
        }

    $(window).load(function(){

        $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
            document.uploader.setEnabled(false);
            if(bCancel){ document.uploader.cancel();} 
        }); 
    });
```

I open the page with the uploader on it in a new tab from the main site and want to close it when they cancel the upload. When I open the tab in IE, however, I instantly get the alert saying `The webpage you are viewing is trying to close this tab. Do you want to close this tab? [OK] [Cancel]` and my uploader is both inaccessible because of the `setEnabled(false)` call and cancelled because of the `cancel()` call.

What I'm looking for is the same functionality, just in IE. I know there are many many *many* issues in IE with events like onbeforeunload with it triggering in response to different things, but I've checked for all of those problems in my site and haven't found anything. I haven't run into anything online that deals with the kind of problem I'm having.

I've tried wrapping the onbeforeunload function in different things such as the load function above as well as `$(document).ready()`, but they either give me the same problems or create new ones.

Comment: [Microsoft's Documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx) shows triggers that will invoke the `beforeunload` event, so you might want to look them over and see if you code is doing any of them.  As an aside, my favorite line from that page is "There are no standards that apply here." That should be the IE development team's motto.

Comment: @MrOBrian I've looked over that page more than any other, probably. When I talk to the other guys I work with they laughed at the ridiculous things that onbeforeunload triggers on. document.write()? Yeah, that unloads the page. Clicking on an anchor? But of course, we're leaving the page!

Comment: I'm wondering if the uploader you are using does document.write, or any other myriad of triggers listed on that page. What about changing it to be more like the example on their page? Maybe try `window.onbeforeunload = ...` instead of `$(window).bind`?

Comment: @MrOBrian, sir, you hit the nail on the head. The uploader does indeed call document.write and I didn't even think to look there. Throw yourself in the answers and I will gladly give you credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [Microsoft's Ridiculous Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx) Then make sure none of the code you are using does anything they list as a trigger to invoke `beforeunload`, which includes several things that do not actually unload the page (go Microsoft!)