# Removing or Distinguishing what triggers an event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events, japplet

It's a situation that I'm sure every web developer has encountered, but IE is not performing how I want it to. Currently the issue is that it's firing [onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when the page is not unloading. I've already asked about this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549856/ie9-firing-onbeforeunload-event-when-the-window-opens), and I've resolved any `document.write()` issues, any anchors and all the other ridiculous things that cause the page to "unload" according to Microsoft. That is, so far as I can tell. The event is still being triggered at times when it shouldn't be.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can flag what causes an event to trigger or to remove anything that would cause it to trigger that is a bit ridiculous. Either to prevent having to deal with it or to work around whatever may be causing the event to happen.

If the answer is a simple 'no' I'll hang my head and keep trying to work around this ridiculous browser, but I figured I'd try and pick the brains of an intelligent crowd before giving up.

### More Info

I am using [jfileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549856/ie9-firing-onbeforeunload-event-when-the-window-opens) on this page. Here is the code for the events. `bCancel` is set to `false` at the very beginning of the page so that none of this occurs unless the upload has started. `canClose` is set to `true` at the beginning so that cancelling the upload doesn't call for the window to close again. The event `onbeforeunload` is triggered right after a file has finished uploading through the applet.

```
        document.uploader.setEnabled(true);

        function JSTransferTriggered(){
            bCancel=true;
        }

        function JSTransferDone(){
            bCancel=false;
            window.open("uploads_finished.php",'_self',null);
        }

        function JSTransferCancelled(){
            $.ajax({
               'async': false,
               'type': 'POST',
               'url': 'cancel.php'              
            });
            bCancel=false;
            if(canClose)self.close();
        }
    $(window).load(function(){  
        $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
            document.uploader.setEnabled(false);
            if(bCancel){
                canClose=false;
                document.uploader.cancel();
            }           
        });
    });
```

The uploader uses other functions similar to `JSTransfertriggered` and `JSTransferDone` and so forth to call when certain events occur in the applet. Those functions have not been altered and all they do is call a function `log` which looks like this:

```
        function log() {
            var msg = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '');

            var match = msg.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)\((.*)\)/);
            if (match) {
                msg = ["<span class='fname'>", match[1], '</span>',
                       "<span class='p'>(</span>",
                       match[2],
                       "<span class='p'>)</span><br>"].join('');
            }
            //msg = msg.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]+/, "<span class='fname'>$&</span>");

            var elt = document.getElementById('event_log');
            //elt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg + "\n"));
            elt.innerHTML += msg;
        }
```

I'm not claiming I've perfectly or completely cleared the page of all listed triggers. I'm trying to figure out a way to find what *is* triggering the event so I can fix it.

Comment: *"That is, so far as I can tell. The event is still being triggered at times when it shouldn't be."* When? Show us an example. (Code in the question, ideally also a link to http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com.) As the answer to your other question pointed out, [the list of things that trigger the event is quite long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), clearly you have at least one of them remaining. If you genuinely believe you don't, show us, and we'll help you find it (or we'll add voices to your claim that they have triggers they haven't listed).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A jsfiddle won't accomplish this. It's being triggered when an applet I'm using finishes uploading a file. I'm editing the post now to give a bit more information on the applet and the calls it makes.